# What are the memory ordering guarantees of the ARM processors?

Tags: memory, arm

I'm new to ARM. Does anyone know where I can find the documentation that provides an overview of the memory ordering of the ARM architecture? I'm talking about the ARM version of Section 8.2 of the Intel Manual, for example (see [here](http://www.google.cl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGcQFjAC&url=http://www.multicoreinfo.com/research/papers/2008/damp08-intel64.pdf&ei=JyQTUKnGKo6o8QTfxYHIDQ&usg=AFQjCNE_VNXAgVGC9NYzHGtyMvdJHkLj1g&sig2=yuRu8RlQIHCDY2Z-dfCbLQ))

Comment: to some extent I think intel has created a problem bad enough to have to document it.  Others dont create these problems.  your best bet is a combination of the TRM for the core and the AMBA/AXI spec which specifies the transfer types.  A lot has to do with the vendors implementation of the AMBA/AXI bus and not ARM itself as the bus is very flexible to allow parallel things to happen or forced to wait for one before starting another.

Answer (score 0):

The Cortex A9 is the first ARM CPU where memory ordering was not straightforward: it has multi-core and has out-of-order execution.

Your best bet is the [documentation section on ARM's website](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp) (registration required).  If that doesn't suffice, they will certainly be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link in ARM info center which stated complete Ordering requirements for memory accesses. Hope it helps.

[Ordering requirements for memory accesses](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0360f/BABCDDGD.html)